# What is the word used to say about the person talk with pride about their place?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Its very common with the people whoever moved from their hometown to new place use to mention and compare everything in the new place with the hometown and will say that their hometown was great/good.

and if two or more from same town unite in new place then the talk about the their hometown will slightly overdose to the third person.

what is the word or phrase to be used to express the situation and people who talk about the greatness of their hometown often in their talk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb [**to brag**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brag) is probably what one would use in a situation similar to the one you described in your example:

> say something in a boastful manner

Example:

> They're always **bragging** about their hometown.